# PyObject_Call no funciona al sobrescribir WndProc en una aplicación en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy intentando extender python con c++ para poder crear un ThumbnailToolbar al estilo del [reproductor multimedia de windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#thumbnail-toolbars) con una aplicación en tkinter.

Y todo va perfectamente, el ThumbnailToolbar se crea, puedo dar funcionalidad a los botones sobrescribiendo el WndProc... El problema viene cuando en WndProc intento hacer uso de algo de python, como **PyObject_Call(pFuncs[0], PyTuple_New(0), NULL);**, donde pFuncs son unas funciones que paso desde python y que funcionan perfectamente si por ejemplo las llamo desde create().

Cuando esto pasa, tkinter y python se cierran automáticamente sin dar ninguna información de error.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (message){
        case WM_COMMAND:{
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)){
                //Se llama si se hace click en el btn1, funciona
                case IDTB_BUTTON1:{
                    MessageBox(0, "Hello world!", "Funciona", MB_OK | MB_USERICON);
                    break;
                }
                //Se llama si se hace click en el btn2, no funciona
                case IDTB_BUTTON2:{
                    Py_Initialize();
                    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello World from Embedded Python!!!')");
                    Py_Finalize();
                    break;
                }
                //Se llama si se hace click en el btn3, no funciona
                case IDTB_BUTTON3:{
                    PyObject_Call(pFuncs[0], PyTuple_New(0), NULL);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallWindowProc(wndproc_tk, hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


static PyObject* create(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
    HWND hWnd;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iO!O!O!", &hWnd, &PyFunction_Type, &pFuncs[0], &PyFunction_Type, &pFuncs[1], &PyFunction_Type, &pFuncs[2])){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, " wrong arguments :(");
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }
    
    PyObject_Call(pFuncs[0], PyTuple_New(0), NULL); //Funciona
    wndproc_tk = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
    CreateThumbnailToolbar(hWnd);
    SetWindowLongW(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)WndProc);

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Podría dar todo el código, pero es bastante extenso para ponerlo aquí, y el problema es únicamente en WndProc. No se como formular la pregunta de otra manera, es muy especifica :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, he intentado mil cosas y mágicamente parece ser que he llegado a una solución.

Me he topado con [esto sobre el gil no se porqué](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65664776/gil-released-on-pyobject-call) y he probado a poner:

```
PyGILState_STATE d_gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
PyObject_Call(pFuncs[0], PyTuple_New(0), NULL);
PyGILState_Release(d_gstate);
```

Por qué no? Pues para mi sorpresa ha funcionado. No se si será lo correcto, pero funciona :p.

Lo que no se es si repercutirá a mal en otra cosa a la app, eso es problema futuro.